# Keras Reinforcement Learning

Tags: keras, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to develop kind of AlphaZero chess engine using keras and reinforcement learning. I play ceratin numbers of games and I save data from these games for later learning purposes. When self-play is done I want to train my model with this data. My question is: do I fit model like in the other approaches by:

```
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=losses)
model.fit(x, y, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)
```

or in reinforcement learning it looks different?

Comment: Do you have a working chess game in python already or does that need programming as well?

Comment: I have working chess game, working MCTS and constructed NN model with random weights. NN is connected to MCTS so upper confidence value is based on NN output

Comment: I believe you can use the model.fit() method for RL problems. You can also use Tensorflows tape.gradient for a more hands on/lower-level approach.